# Remote login for router administration

Tags: routes, remote-access

I have set my router to accept remote management. Now I am remote and try to connect to it through its WAN IP (xy.xy.xxx.xxx, checked and it's uptodate), port 20001 (the settings in the router said this is the port).

When I go to the address xy.xy.xxx.xxx:20001, it asks my username/password but shows a blank screen when I input both.

Is the blank screen an indication that I am logged in correctly?

If yes, how can I reach my web admin page, which is normally at 192.168.0.1?

Comment: What make/model of router is it? What browser are you using? You shouldn't be getting a blank page. What happens if you do a page refresh? If the login failed, you would see an error. If it succeeds, you should see a setup page.

Comment: The router is Comtrend Multi DSL router. Can't say more about it now. xy.xy.xxx.xxx:20001 asks for a password. xy.xy.xxx.xxx:44444 for example not, so I think I am not completely lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That your router listen to the right external port is a good first step. The blank page seems for me the result of a wrong authentication, a wrong configuration or a creepy implemented interface.

You can test the following things to get more information what goes wrong

1. Compare the addresses in your browser address bar in case of intranet and wan login. Is it the same?
2. Is somewhere in the router configuration an entry where you restrict the external access to a special user? Maybe a extra user as the standard admin or root stuff is needed. Sometimes if you use ssh only the admin or root account can access. It depends of your router
3. What is the result if you do wrong router login from your intranet site? Do you also got a blank page?
4. Compare the request/response steps while the intranet and the wan access - for instance with firebug.

Maybe you find what's going wrong. But to be honest I don't would open my router gui to the world wild web. If you need to access your router from the internet then use VPN to tunnel your traffic inside in your intranet - there you don't will have any authentication problems :-D

Another way could be to use similar techniques to TeamViewer or NetViewer access your intranet with it and from there to go to your router interface.